# ASP.NET try to sync AJAX call with control

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I have two RadioButtonLists, one is an ASP.NET RadioButtonList, and the other is a series of HTML input radio items with a common group name.

The javascript for the radioButton click has a call to a server side `WebMethod` to set a value then when it returns I want to set one of the radiobuttons in the asp radioncontrol to have the ASP event triggered. This is so that the server will send back a new page with updated objects.

```
 <asp:RadioButtonList Visible="true" 
                      Height="1" Width="1" 
                      ID="MyArticleHistory" 
                      runat="server"    
                      AutoPostBack="true" 
                      OnSelectedIndexChanged="MyArticleHistory_SelectedIndexChanged"  
                      RepeatDirection="Horizontal">
        <asp:ListItem id="OneDayRadioBtn" runat="server" Value="1-Day" />
        <asp:ListItem id="ThreeDayRadioBtn" runat="server" Value="3-Days" />
   </asp:RadioButtonList>

   <input type="radio" 
          name="MyHTMLArticleHistory" 
          id="HtmlOneDay" 
          value="htmlOneDayRadioBtn" 
          checked 
          onchange="OneDayChecked()"> 1-Day
    <input type="radio" 
           name="MyHTMLArticleHistory" 
           id="HtmlThreeDay" 
           value="htmlThreeDayRadioBtn" 
           onchange="ThreeDayChecked()"> 3-Days
```

... Java script is

```
 function OneDayChecked()
 {
     alert("We're inside 1 day");
     PageMethods.setTimeFilter(0);//0 is the index for the 1-day

     document.getElementById('<%=OneDayRadioBtn.Selected%>').value = true;
     //Q: This should cause the asp radio button to change selected index
     //    resulting in a call to the server, correct?
 }
```

How do I trigger the asp radiobutton onSelectedIndexChange from within the javascript?

Answer (score 0):

You Can use the JQuery '.trigger()' method. See http://api.jquery.com/trigger/
Example:
 '$('OneDayRadioBtn').trigger('checked')'